# Sending a message first and then executing code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are developing an iPhone app (for shopping) and have a dotnet application which takes the request coming from the iphone and processes them.

```
    //How it works
```

- iPhone sends the payment details to dotnet application for processing.
- dotnet uses some payment platform from transactions.
- return a message to iPhone whether transaction is  successful or not

  ```
  //How it has to work
  ```
- iPhone sends the payment details to dotnet application for processing.
- Controller immediately returns some message (Just to make sure the that details has been received).
- And the Process the request (actual payment process)
- Notify through email whether transaction is successful or not `//this part is already implemented`

So I need to return a message even before the transaction is processed (to make it more user friendly and not to annoy them by the delay caused for the entire process). After the message is sent it should proceed to actual payment process. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an async library like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: Thank You for giving me an idea. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write your async codes like this :

```
public ActionResult ProcessPayment(PaymentModel model)
{

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //do your payment processing here...
    });

    return view("success blob blob...");
}
```

Note : anyway your solution has no any fallback strategy. What will you do if you failed through payment process or mail sending process?! If you need a comprehensive solution, use `SignalR` components (although it is more complex)